# paperclip gem upload not working in rails 4 multipart form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, multipart, form-for

I'm trying to setup a basic form with the ability to upload a picture, a title and a body of text. I'm using the `paperclip 4.2.1` gem and `rails 4.2.0`.

The form shows up fine, I'm able to type in a title, some body text and select a picture. However, when I submit the form, it skips the show method and goes back to the index page and the image does not get uploaded to the database.

When I submit the form with only the title and body text, it does display in the show method. I did verify the source code of the form page shows "enctype="multipart/form-data". Does anyone know what im missing??

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150310181944) do

create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end
```

end

Model --> article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base


  has_attached_file :image
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

View --> new.html.erb

## New Article

```
<%= form_for @article, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>  

    </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

view ->  index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing articles</h1>


<%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %> 
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Image</th>
  </tr>

 <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= image_tag article.image.url %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

view ->  show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>

<p>

    <%= image_tag @article.image.url %>
</p>


<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Controller --> articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

def index
  @articles = Article.all
end

def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end


def new
  @article = Article.new
end


def create
  @article = Article.create(article_params)

  @article.save
  redirect_to @article

end

private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :image)
  end

end
```

I'm very new to ruby and programming in general, so it's probably some type somewhere but I've been searching for days and I'm not sure why the picture wont upload.

Comment: can you print something in 'show' method, and can you post the params you are getting in 'show' method in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typical validation error in `create` method. Just change `Article.create` to `Article.create!` and you will see error and backtrace. It will help you to investigate and fix problem.

Comment: THANKS for that tip, i added the "bang" option and when i submitted the form_for i got a rails error, "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in ArticlesController#create
Validation failed: Image has an extension that does not match its contents"

Comment: The workaround by glebtv in that forum was to disable paperclip  MediaTypeSpoofDetector by adding a file in the rails project.  Config/initializers/paperclip.rb and in it add this code

Comment: require 'paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector'
    module Paperclip
      class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
        def spoofed?
          false
        end
      end
    end

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector'
module Paperclip
  class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
    def spoofed?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

i added the above code into /config/initializers/paperclip.rb, and now i can upload the pictures fine, everything works !!!

from what ive read so far, It looks like the image attachment was somehow loosing its extension and failing the spoof detector. it might have something to do with the file.exe unix command missing from windows 7, but i tried installing it from

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm

and was still getting the same error,

this workaround was found here:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1429